# Creating an ImageJ Counter

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, imagej

I'm trying to create a counter in ImageJ but I'm running into an issue because the index is out of bounds.  Obviously the issue with is `pathNames[i+1]`.

```
imgGrpCount = 1;
pathNames = newArray("/usr/local/data/1/", "/usr/local/data/1/", "/usr/local/data/2/", "/usr/local/data/2/");

function modifyImgGrpCount(imgGrpCount, pathNames, i) {
    for(j = 0; j < pathNames.length; j++) {
        if ( (pathNames[i] == pathNames[i+1]) ) {
            imgGrpCount++;
        } else {
            imgGrpCount = 1;
        }
        return imgGrpCount;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions with the logic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't understand why you use i in the if condition - what is i? I think it should be j due to the for-loop.
If my guess is right that it is ment to be j in the if than you must wrap this if with another where you ask if you are at the last element:

```
function modifyImgGrpCount(imgGrpCount, pathNames, i) {
    for(j = 0; j < pathNames.length; j++) {
      if(j!=pathNames.length-1) { //or j<pathNames.length-1
        if ( (pathNames[j] == pathNames[j+1]) ) {
            imgGrpCount++;
        } else {
            imgGrpCount = 1;
        }
      }
        return imgGrpCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pathNames[i+1]` when i=3 is throw this exception. You can run the loop to `pathNames.length-1`. It just a temp solution because I don't understand your purpose when run this code. Your counter is alway equal 1 or 2. Please share your purpose to get more support